# SSH connection refused error in Ubuntu's Docker image

Tags: ubuntu, docker, ssh, ubuntu-16.04, openssh

I am trying to enable SSH on the docker images of Ubuntu but it is throwing following error "ssh: connect to host moby port 22: Connection refused"

The attached image shows that[image]

- Command 1 : No firewall is installed.
- Command 2 : openssh-server is installed
- Command 3 : openssh-client is installed
- Command 4 : The ssh service is also running
- Command 5 : Netstat show sshd is listening on port 22
- Command 6 : Hostname is "moby"
- Command 7 : ssh-keygen has generated all the files
- Command 8 : Command "ssh root@moby" is still throwing connection refused error.

Also in file /etc/ssh/sshd_config , PermitRootLogin is set to yes [image]

Can somebody please help me why I am not able to ssh ?

Comment: Just because your docker container's hostname is `moby`, does not mean that hostname actually resolves to the docker container's IP address! Try changing `moby` to `localhost` in the `ssh` command.

Comment: How can I make my hostname resolve to container's IP address ? @RobinGreen

Comment: The easiest way is to edit `/etc/hosts` (Google it)